# Excel macro execution taking long time

Tags: excel, vba

The following macro is working fine at debugging stage, but when you execute on a worksheet keeps on executing for more than 15 minutes. I have 47126 rows of data. and also how to minimize the code?

```
Sub RAmount()

Dim Month As Range, rAmnt As Range, tprem As Range


Dim a As Range, c As Long


Set Month = Range("V2:V" & Range("V65000").End(xlUp).Row)

Set tprem = Range("R2:R" & Range("R65000").End(xlUp).Row)

Set rAmnt = Range("Y2:Y" & Range("Y65000").End(xlUp).Row)

c = 2


For Each a In tprem

     If Cells(c, 22) = 0 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1)
                
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 1 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.00792)
        
        
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 2 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.01583)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 3 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.02375)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 4 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.03167)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 5 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.03958)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 6 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.0475)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 7 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.0558)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 8 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.06408)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 9 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.07238)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 10 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.08067)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 11 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.08896)
     
     ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 12 Then
        Cells(c, 25) = Round(a * 1.09726)
     
     Else
        Cells(c, 25) = 0
        

    End If

c = c + 1

If c > 47126 Then

    Exit For

End If

Next a
          
End Sub
```

Comment: Tested the code removing the round function. In a split second execution completed. How the round function making the code to take long time. Please let me know. Thank you

Comment: A basic optimization: if (eg) your code gets to `ElseIf Cells(c, 22) = 12` then at that point you've read the value from `Cells(c, 22)` 13 times...   Read the value once into a variable, and then check it.

Comment: @var Sorry to say but executing `Round` 47126 times does not take 15 minutes and nobody is going to think this is the only thing you changed. If you could at least confirm what happens when you restore `Round` in your code, remove it again, then repeat several times with or without restarting Excel between each try, the situation may be different. Even so, I'm afraid more information is going to be needed.

Comment: Thank you. Yes after removing and executing the code it worked fine but when I tried again to test it then its taking the same time.

Answer (score 1):

The code in the question uses ranges incorrectly:

1. Accessing cells 1 by 1 is slow. It is far more efficient to work on whole ranges at once, both for reading and for writing.
   For writing, especially, you trigger a `Change` event on your sheet (since you write into 47126 cells, you trigger a recalculation of the entire sheet 47126 times, not to mention each calculation event takes a longer time the bigger your sheet grows...). This will be especially visible the more formulas you have, and more so if you use volatile functions such as `RAND()`.
2. Even though you defined `Month`, `tPrem` and `rAmnt`, you keep using the `Cells` method of your worksheet.

An easy solution (not what I recommend for your case but it could be useful in a different context) is to stop the application from doing 3 things that it automatically does when writing in a cell:

- Processing events
- Calculating
- Refreshing the screen

To do it, you only have to surround the body of your method like so:

```
Sub RAmount()
    Dim currentCalcMode
    currentCalcMode = Application.Calculation
    Application.Calculation = xlCalculationManual
    Application.EnableEvents = False
    Application.ScreenUpdating = false

    'Your code

    Application.Calculation = currentCalcMode
    Application.EnableEvents = True
    Application.ScreenUpdating = True
    If currentCalcMode <> xlCalculationManual Then Application.Calculate
End Sub
```

The correct solution, however, is to stop working with individual cells and work with entire ranges instead. Doing so will trigger the 3 things I mention above only once so there really is no need to bother deactivating/reactivating them. The ranges in your code are small enough to fit in memory.

The full code including some simplifications looks like this:

```
Sub RAmount()
'factorValues contains a series of multipliers
    Dim factorValues
    factorValues = Array(1#, 1.00792, 1.01583, 1.02375, 1.03167, 1.03958, 1.0475, 1.0558, 1.06408, 1.07238, 1.08067, 1.08896, 1.09726)
    
    Dim tprem As Variant, Month As Variant
'Extract all the values of the R:R and V:V columns
    With Range("R2")
        tprem = Application.Intersect(.CurrentRegion, .CurrentRegion.Offset(1), .EntireColumn).Value
    End With
    With Range("V2")
        Month = Application.Intersect(.CurrentRegion, .CurrentRegion.Offset(1), .EntireColumn).Value
    End With
'Discover the first index of arrays (can be altered by Option Base)
    Dim minIndex As Long, colIndex As Long 
    minIndex = LBound(factorValues)
    colIndex = LBound(Month, 2)
    
    Dim result As Variant
    ReDim result(LBound(Month) To UBound(Month))
    
    Dim i As Long
    For i = LBound(Month) To UBound(Month)
        If Month(i, colIndex) >= 1 And Month(i, colIndex) <= 12 Then
            result(i) = VBA.Round(tprem (i, colIndex) * factorValues(minIndex + Month (i, colIndex)))
        Else
            result(i) = 0#
        End If
    Next i
    
'Place the entire result array into column Y:Y (the result needs to be transposed to form a column of values instead of a row)
    Range("Y2").Resize(1 + UBound(result) - LBound(result), 1).Value = Application.Transpose(result)
End Sub
```

Comment: Thank you very much. As I am a vb learner I am going through the code step by step  to understand it. It worked fine.